# How can I write a contains_var functon using fold on OCaml?

Tags: expression, ocaml

I have the following `fold_expr` function which recursively folds over any arbitrary expression including floats, variables, binary operators and negations.

```
let rec fold_expr (e : expression) (f: float -> 'a) (v: 'a) (b: binop -> 'a -> 'a -> 'a)  (n: 'a -> 'a)
```

Now I am trying to implement a function called `contains_var` which returns true if an expression has a variable and false if not. I know that `contains_var` can be implemented recursively as such:

```
let rec contains_var (e:expression) : bool =
  match e with
  | Num _ -> false
  | Var -> true
  | Neg _ -> false
  | Binop (_, e1, e2) -> contains_var e1 || contains_var e2
;;
```

I tried implementing it as follows:

```
let contains_var (e:expression) : bool =
        let Num _ = false in
        let Var = true in
        let Binop bin, l, r = l || r in
        let Neg _ = false
                fold_expr e _ Var bin _
```

Obviously I have trouble compiling and I am sure I am missing something. Any help is appreciated! :)

Comment: Why does `fold_expr` have a `(f : float -> 'a)` functions as a parameter?

Comment: Actually, can you show the implementation of `fold_expr`, I can't quite understand what this function does

Comment: @Lhooq I actually dont have an implementation for fold_expr It was just given as a bonus function to us and we were asked to implement a couple other functions using that.

Comment: Do you have some documentation for this function?

Comment: Fold for expressions needs to take four things, all of which take a different kind of expression and return
1. What to do on a Num. This is a float -> ’a because it needs to know the number.
2. What to do on a Var. Like the base case for lists and trees, this is just a ’a because there’s no other
information at a Var.
3. What to do on a Binop. This is a binop -> ’a -> ’a -> ’a because it needs to know the operation
and the result of folding over both subexpressions.
4. What to do on a Neg. This is a ’a -> ’a because it just needs to know the result of folding over
the subexpression

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the look of `fold_expr`, it looks like this function does the following thing:

```ml
val fold_expr (e : expression) (f: float -> 'a) (v: 'a) (b: binop -> 'a -> 'a -> 'a)  (n: 'a -> 'a)
```

`fold_expr e f v b n`:

- applies `f` to `n` if `e` is `Num n`,
- returns `v` if `e` is `Var`,
- applies `b` to `bop`, `fold_epxr e1` and `fold_expr e2` if `e` is `Binop (bop, e1, e2)`
- and applies `n` to `e1` if `e` is `Neg e1`

What you have to do is to provide values corresponding to your problem to fold_expr. In this case, functions that return `false` for each case except `Var` and `Binop`

A solution might look like this:

```ml
let contains_var e = fold_expr e (fun _ -> false) true what_is_b (fun _ -> false)
```

I could give you `what_is_b` but I think that's the main problem you need to find by yourself so I'll leave it to you.

Comment: So I tried smthg like this:  let Binop (bin, p1, p2) = p1 || p2 in
        fold_expr e (fun _ -> false) true bin (fun _ -> false)

Comment: But I keep getting the Unbound value error at p1

Comment: I wrote a mistake actually. b is applied to fold_expr e1 and fold_expr e2, not e1 and e2

Comment: You can't create a function starting with an capital letter. And you declare `Binop` but then you use it by calling `bin`, that's strange

Answer (score 0):

A fold can be seen as a way to reinterpret constructors.
For a list defined as

```ml
type 'a l =
  | Nil
  | Cons of 'a * 'a l
```

the fold(right) function can written as

```ml
let rec fold ~nil ~cons = function
| Nil -> nil
| Cons (x,l) -> cons x (fold ~cons ~nil l)
```

From this point, writing a deep identity function can be done by rewriting the constructor as function:

```ml
let deep_identity l = fold ~nil:Nil ~cons:(fun x l -> Cons (x,l))
```

Similarly, a (tautological) function `contains_nil` can be written as

```
let contains_nil = fold ~nil:true ~cons:(fun _ contains_nil -> contains_nil)
```

The `fold_expr` function  is just a slightly more complicated version, that takes a functional version of `Var`, `Num`, `Binop` and `Neg` as an argument.
Thus, to write a contains_var function you need to:

- define the right `var`, `num`, `binop` and `neg` functions
- call `fold_expr` with the functions defined above.

Note that functions and variables names cannot starts with a capital letter; and you cannot use `_` as an argument to a function application.